# Sane settings to show context when doing search and replace in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, replace, query-replace, visibility

If I run certain functions like `isearch-forward` (with <kbd>C-s</kbd>) in an org-mode buffer, all content become temporarily visible. When I end the search, headings automagically collapse the way they were before I searched. Nice.

But if I run something like `query-replace` (with <kbd>M-%</kbd>), trees stay collapsed. The point essentially hidden inside them. I am asked to confirm a change that I can't see. That's not good at all!

Surely functions like `query-replace` should behave more like `isearch-forward` does. I swear I found a simple solution to this at some point. (A variable with a `smart` setting, I thought?) But I seem to have lost track of it. Please help me.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`, to suggest this as a feature enhancement.

Comment: I see you've done that. Great.

Comment: In the meantime I'll leave this open in case someone has a simple fix.  Maybe some sort of hook using `org-show-context`? This is driving me nuts because I'm 99% sure I found a fix for this online somewhere and somehow lost track of it.

Comment: I went digging in my init and realized I already have this line: `(setq org-catch-invisible-edits (quote smart))`. Maybe this just stopped working because a recent upgrade in org-mode. (I'm running the version on ELPA.)

Comment: Maybe you want the value `show` instead of `smart`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try in GNU Emacs 24.4 or 24.5 where it should work as you want.

Comment: Thanks. I wish the Ubuntu repo would update emacs, but I guess it might be time to try building it myself.